# How to check if TABLE creation was successful in Sqlite (python)?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

An EXISTS is no good since I need to know whether this particular function was the reason behind a successful Table creation or not, not whether the table exists (since it might already exist from somewhere else). If the function successfully created the table, something will happen. If it didn't (the table already exists, doesn't exist but table creation still failed) then nothing will happen.

It's easy to check if SELECT successfully selected something (eg: c.fetchone()[0] > 0), it's easy to check if UPDATE succesfully updated something (eg: c.rowcount>=1), how to easily check if CREATE TABLE successfully created a table?

Comment: Do a select on the table, if it raises an exception the operation failed.

Comment: What if the table already exists from somewhere else though? I need to know if this particular function created the table or not

Comment: double check if it existed before creation

Comment: @Evgeny Pogrebnyak I don't get why common sense things like this blow over me sometimes, thanks

Comment: what happens is that you are trying to isolate a very particular behaviour on sqlite and in reality there is not silver bullet for you. why not try show implementation these down-to earth suggestions and ask `hey, is there a better way I can do this`? question swith code/attempt attract more attention and that way you can probably lear something unexpected, eg if this can be done the way you expect in other databases other than sqlite